# concurrency of ejabberd community?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

you know what is the concurrency of ejabberd community? how many user can receive a pubsub.
I have seen the limitations of the ejabberd server in its official website, and I have doubts about it, after entering the data of my card an executable is downloaded and if they provide advice for server configuration.

```
https://ejabberd-saas.com
```

what are all the benefits of hiring ejabberd saas

Comment: And if you put this?
> 127.0.0.1     server.com

Comment: ok, i change the ask..

Comment: hey @Badlop sorry you can help, i want try this service in my job?